# Flutter drop down works but doesn't display updated value

Tags: flutter, dart

My dropdown menu works properly after selecting a new option, but the new selection doesn't update the currently displayed option after its changed.

```
Widget buildCarDropdown() {
    return
        Center(
          child: DropdownButton(
            hint: Text('Please choose a car make'),
            value: currentLease.carMake,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                currentLease.carMake = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: carMakes.map((String make) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text(make),
                value: make,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
  }
```

carMakes is just an array of strings

currentLease contains a string for the selection of make. The value is set correctly after changing it in currentLease, and displays correctly if the widget is reloaded.

Everything seems proper here to me, not sure why it doesn't display updates properly.

Edit: What I mean by not updating it, that the drop down opens displaying all the options. Say it started at "Honda", you can then select "Acura" and though the currentLease.carMake gets updated properly, the drop down stays displaying "Honda" until it is reloaded.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "_but the new selection doesn't update the currently displayed option after its changed_"?

Comment: By any chance are you initializing currentLease object in build/or some sort of method, but not in the state class?

Comment: So I fixed this by breaking my save menu out to it's own widget. I think it had to do with SetState refreshing the wrong widget because mine only came from a function.